# How can i parse the SIM808 raw GPS data?

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have the [makerfab sim808](https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/sim808-gps-module.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwiurXBRAnEiwAk2GFZuxg5hvwKlprw3_mZ6TUVe5CUmiP-Km5bFLZXUVqq35Eq0nuY0mayBoCK_8QAvD_BwE#Useful-Links) and the documentation does not specify what is what that is returned in the gps raw data. The following is the data, has anyone worked with this and can let me know what is what.

`GPS raw data: 1,1,20180518182755.000,43.479312,-80.524750,337.700,0.06,203.8,1,,1.6,4.9,4.6,,8,7,,,43,,`

I found [this](https://github.com/DFRobot/DFRobot_SIM808) by DFRobot, anyone have any idea if this is right.

Answer (score 0):

should have just found the documentation :/ https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SIM808_GPS_Application_Note_V1.00.pdf